syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '=' (SyntaxError)
Letters1 = Array["A","B"]
password1 = nil
while password1 != "A"
  letter1 = Letters1[rand(0...2)]
  letter2 = Letters1[rand(0...2)]
  password1 = (letter1)
  File.write("passwords.txt",password1)
  puts password1
end

Works but when i assign two values to password1 then i get unexpected "(" error
Letters1 = Array["A","B"]
password1 = nil
while password1 != "AB"
  letter1 = Letters1[rand(0...2)]
  letter2 = Letters1[rand(0...2)]
  password1 = (letter1, letter2)
  File.write("passwords.txt",password1)
  puts password1
end

Unexpected "(", expecting "=" Line "password1 = (letter1, letter2)"
How can I assign two array values to a variable?
I tried actually putting = instead of a (.
password1 = (letter1, letter2 = password1)
But it doesn't actually print out anything and it should end the loop when the values of password1 are "AB" and it doesn't end.

password1 = letter1, letter2

What do you expect password1 = (letter1, letter2) to do?

"password1 = (letter1, letter2)" is not valid syntax in Ruby, hence the error being thrown
although
"password1 = (letter1)" is.
To concatenate strings use password1 = letter1 + letter2 or the join method.
Code could do with a few other tweaks - an example given below

open the file once (outside the loop),close when done.
use the (preferable) sample method to randomly select from the array

Letters1 = ["A", "B"]
password1 = nil

fh = File.open("passwords.txt", "a" )

while password1 != "AB"
  letter1 = Letters1.sample
  letter2 = Letters1.sample
  password1 = letter1 + letter2
  fh.puts( password1 + "\n" )
  puts password1
end

fh.close()


Better: File.open("passwords.txt", "a") do |fh| ... end
